# Batch rename files with looping

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch code. The problem is that when I run the batch file, the screenshot file is stored in correct directory, but the batch code doesn't rename the files. If the batch file is in the same directory then only the renaming is done correctly.

```
@echo off
:strt
myprogram savescreenshot "A:\Some Folder\New folder\scr~$currtime.HH_mm_ss$.png"
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "chars=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
set mydir=A:\Folder\New folder
:: (tried this too) PATH=%PATH%;A:\Folder\New folder\*.png
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%mydir%\*.png"') do call :renameFile "%%F"
exit /b

:renameFile
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:retry
set "name="
for /l %%N in (1 1 32) do (
  set /a I=!random!%%36
  for %%I in (!I!) do set "name=!name!!chars:~%%I,1!"
)
if exist "!name!.png" goto :retry
endlocal & ren %1 {%name%}
::ping 192.0.2.0 -n 1 -w 10000 >nul
goto strt
```

I think it has something to do with this line:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "A:\Some folder\New\New folder\*.png"') do call :renameFile "%%F"
```

If I change the line to this

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.png') do call :renameFile "%%F"
```

it works perfect.

Comment: Still does'nt work! I am a noob, please help.

Comment: I think it is something to do with this line:

    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "A:\Some folder\New\New folder\*.png"') do call :renameFile "%%F"
If i keep it like this:

    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.png') do call :renameFile "%%F"
It works perfect

Comment: [Magoo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) tried to help you on this issue. But the problem for us is that question is very unclear. What should this batch file do? What is the name of the PNG file created by `myprogram`? Why do you uses drive `A:` and not drive `C:`? We can't test the batch file with `A:`. Why does `myprogram` create the PNG files in `A:\Some Folder\New folder`, but rest of batch code runs on `A:\Folder\New folder` which is a different folder? Best would be to explain in words what the batch file should do on a practical file example. And why an endless loop?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
:strt
myprogram savescreenshot "A:\Some Folder\New folder\scr~$currtime.HH_mm_ss$.png"
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "chars=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
set "mydir=A:\Folder\New folder"
pushd "%mydir%"
:: (tried this too) PATH=%PATH%;A:\Folder\New folder\*.png
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "*.png"') do call :renameFile "%%F"
POPD
exit /b

:renameFile
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:retry
set "name="
for /l %%N in (1 1 32) do (
  set /a I=!random!%%36
  for %%I in (!I!) do set "name=!name!!chars:~%%I,1!"
)
if exist "!name!.png" goto :retry
endlocal & ren %1 {%name%}
::ping 192.0.2.0 -n 1 -w 10000 >nul
goto :eof
```

Note changes :

`mydir` setting - add quotes to ensure trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned (general principles)

`pushd`/`popd` bracket - changes current directory to `mydir` and restores original

`eol=:` eliminated from `for` - not required as `delims=` will assign the entire line to `%%F`

The `exit/b` could be replaced by `goto :eof` with the same effect

Final `goto changed to`:eof`. This terminates the subroutine`:renamefile`and returns to the`for`loop. Going to`strt`means that the entire procedure is re-run, starting with`savescreenshot`, presumably creating yet another file and renaming the very first randomly, repeat ad infinitum.

You haven't sated what your file is supposed to do. It would appear to be endlessly re-running `savescreenshot` and then renaming the first file matching `*.png` that it locates.

If you were to change the filemask in the `for ...%%F` from `*.png` to `*-*.png` then only those names which have yet to be renamed will be renamed (`savescreenshot` appears to generate the name **"scr~$currtime.HH_mm_ss$.png"** in the target directory. This is an ordinary literal name unless `savescreenshot` is processing it somehow. so the file **"scr~$currtime.HH_mm_ss$.png"** would created and overwritten in the original process over and over again. "*-*.png" would target just the latest-created file since it is the only one containing `-` - your renaming routine changes it to a filename **not** containing `-`.